# how to sync two ftp server by python

Tags: python, ftp, synchronization

I have two FTP server a and b, I need to copy files from a server to b server. Downloading the file from a and upload to b is too complicate, I want to write a script by python to do this on my desktop, just type the command below it will do the job.

```
 python syncftp.py a.com(source server) folder(folder name in source server) 
        b. com(destination server) folder(destination folder name)
```

but after some google, still can't find a good way to sync two ftp server just like dropbox. Is there any other way to do this? thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters, you have http://www.csync.org/ which is sort of a rsync (but since rsync only works with SSH and not FTP) but for HTTP/FTP transfers.

If you don't like that option there's always "lftp" or "curlftpfs", stackoverflow has a sister-site which provides your answer:

https://serverfault.com/questions/24622/how-to-use-rsync-over-ftp

if THAT doesn't give you anything, well then you always have ftplib in python:
http://docs.python.org/library/ftplib.html

```
from ftplib import FTP
ftpretr = FTP('get.ftp.com')   # connect to host, default port
ftpretr.login()               # user anonymous, passwd anonymous@
ftpretr.retrbinary('RETR README', open('README', 'wb').write)
ftpretr.quit()
ftpsend = FTP('send-to.ftp.com','login','password')
ftpsend.storbinary('STOR todo.txt', open('README','rb'))
ftpsend.quit()
```

Now i can't help you more then that tbh without doing everything for you and i'm guessing you want to learn? use sys.argv[] to fetch input/output files and also for source-host and desition perhaps.

Enjoy! :)

Comment: Which option is the fastest?

Answer (score -1):

This sounds like a job for [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) to me. As the name lets suggest, it can recursively sync files and directories (also with compression and other stuff).

Comment: Per @Torxed, rsync, gift of the gods it may be, does not support FTP, just SSH and it's own protocol. No love there.